Programmatic selection of SAML config/url upon login
Salesforce allows an org to have multiple SAML configurations under Single Sign on settings. Under My domain  one can modify the authentication configuration and select multiple SAML configs under the Authentication service. This allows the user to select any one of these configs on the login screen.
What I want to do is allow the user to login and then redirect them to the right SAML config/URL based on their profile or permission set automatically.
Is this possible and if so how?
Thank You

What you're asking doesn't make sense. What exactly are you trying to do? See X-Y Problem.

This problem is called Identity Provider (IdP) Discovery.  Out oft the box solution is Login Discovery. We've done this for our customers without Login Discovery with custom code and other hijinks but yeah.

@identigral that is exactly what I was looking for. Can you make this an answer and I will accept. Thank you

@sfdcfox Trying to not confuse banking clients with multiple IDP's on login screen.
